# Events Not Searchable in Register Participant Form

Tags: civievent

Environment:

- Drupal 7.63
- CiviCRM 5.9.1
- PHP 7.0

We have seen this in two sites with this environment so far, immediately after updating to 5.9.1.

The Problem:

1. Go to a contact page.
2. Click on the Events tab.
3. Click on Add Event Registration.
4. The "Event" box says "- select event -" but is not searchable and does not show the dropdown of events.

[image: screenshot of issue described above]

Note that it does work if you get to this same form through some the Manage Events dashboard or through the direct "Register Event Participant" link on the menu. It's only if you do it through the contact page that it fails.

Comment: I'm unable to replicate this, but here are some troubleshooting steps: First, is it a matter of the form loading as a page vs. a modal (aka "pop-up")?  Try right-clicking "Add Event Registration" and opening in a new tab.  Second, do you have Javascript errors on your page?  Press F12 to open your browser's dev tools and select the "Console" tab.  If so, please edit your question to include the text of any Javascript errors.

Comment: Thanks Jon G. Yes, it does work if I open in new window instead of as a pop-up. And yes, it does show a JavaScript error (both as pop-up or new window), so I can think we can narrow it down to an old custom template that doesn't work with the newest Civi version.